# PHP find duplicates on specific index in multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional Array

```
 array(616) {
    [3]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(1)
      [3]=>
      string(11) "Abdul Malik"
      [4]=>
      object(DateTime)#1408 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "1999-04-20 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
      }
      [5]=>
      string(15) "35302-2009157-1"
      [6]=>
      string(1) "c"
      [7]=>
      string(12) "Abdul Khaliq"
      [8]=>
      string(12) "0333-4255236"
      [9]=>
      string(25) "haidertraderssp@yahoo.com"
      [10]=>
      string(56) "Flat # 3, 2nd Floor, 62 Jahanzeb Block Iqbal Town,Lahore"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(3)
      [3]=>
      string(12) "Sarwar Masih"
      [4]=>
      object(DateTime)#1383 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2009-09-09 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
      }
      [5]=>
      string(15) "35202-7192131-1"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "O+"
      [7]=>
      string(12) "Khadim Masih"
      [8]=>
      string(12) "0306-4516165"
      [9]=>
      string(25) "haidertraderssp@yahoo.com"
      [10]=>
      string(56) "Flat # 3, 2nd Floor, 62 Jahanzeb Block Iqbal Town,Lahore"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      int(3)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(172)
      [3]=>
      string(12) "Shahid Abbas"
      [4]=>
      object(DateTime)#1409 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2018-10-03 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
      }
      [5]=>
      string(15) "36102-5885445-9"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "A+"
      [7]=>
      string(7) "Jamshed"
      [8]=>
      string(12) "0309-8562084"
      [9]=>
      string(25) "haidertraderssp@yahoo.com"
      [10]=>
      string(56) "Flat # 3, 2nd Floor, 62 Jahanzeb Block Iqbal Town,Lahore"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      int(4)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(240)
      [3]=>
      string(8) "Asim Ali"
      [4]=>
      object(DateTime)#1384 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2020-02-01 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
      }
      [5]=>
      string(15) "33102-1634076-7"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "B+"
      [7]=>
      string(12) "Amir Shehzad"
      [8]=>
      string(12) "0302-8003835"
      [9]=>
      string(25) "haidertraderssp@yahoo.com"
      [10]=>
      string(56) "Flat # 3, 2nd Floor, 62 Jahanzeb Block Iqbal Town,Lahore"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      int(5)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(13)
      [3]=>
      string(12) "Sultan Ahmad"
      [4]=>
      object(DateTime)#1406 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2004-10-17 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(12) "Asia/Karachi"
      }
      [5]=>
      string(15) "35302-4226199-1"
      [6]=>
      string(2) "O+"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "Faiz Ahmed"
      [8]=>
      string(12) "0302-5536832"
      [9]=>
      string(25) "haidertraderssp@yahoo.com"
      [10]=>
      string(56) "Flat # 3, 2nd Floor, 62 Jahanzeb Block Iqbal Town,Lahore"
    }
```

i want to check if there's any duplicate value on inner array's specific index such as, check all array's for index 1 and 5. No value at index 1 should be repeated in any other array's index 1 and same as index 5.

> I have tried PHP's `array_unique()` function but it only checks the whole array not index.

Please tell me if there's any method so i don't have to use loop, as data is coming from an excel file and might be much large to loop through every single array.

Comment: If you can add the data using `var_export()` instead, it can help others reproduce your problem without having to do a lot of work to get some test data.

Comment: try using foreach loop on the array, and then converting object into array if object given on the index and then user array_unique on the single array. You can put a check that the array is single array or multidimensional array inside each index

Comment: Use `array_column` to extract the values from column x into a new array. Then compare the count of that array, with the count after you applied `array_unique` to it - if those don’t match, then you had duplicates in those values in column x.